# Debian with only bind9 crash unexpected, where to look for the issue?

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, bind

I´m running an Debian (jessie) OS with bind9 as DNS service. Since I started with that system I have some unexpected system issues. From time to time DNS isn´t any longer working (e.g. the users got a timeout) and I need to restart the whole machine, then its working again. I tried to rebuild it (as there isn´t that much config and its DNS service is only used by a handful users).

Any ideas where I can start troubleshooting that issue? I can administrate a Linux OS but I´m not a pro if it comes to the troubleshooting from such issues.

thanks :=)

Comment: look at log files

Comment: yes but which one?